# How to access shared folder on Windows without prompting username/password?

Tags: java, windows, file-upload, selenium, shared-directory

My selenium and java based application needs to frequently read/upload a small-size file from a shared folder (`\\some-server-ip\SharedfolderName`).

When I run the application on multiple client machine (both server and clients can see their IPs) I am prompted to provide username and password to connect to server IP before the application can access the shared folder.

I have  shared folder given `full control` privileges to `everyone`, `anonymous logon` group.

I also added `\\some-server-ip\SharedfolderName` to local security policy's

> Network access: Shares that can be accessed anonymously

But, it is not working.

Interestingly, if I enter the username/password manually first time, it works fine in subsequent runs on that particular client. I cannot manually enter username/passwords on all 700+ of the client machines.

I have been trying to get this to work from past three days, without much success.
Any help/suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. I have been trying different OS (2008, 2003, Win7) for hosting the shared folder, in a desperate hope to get it to work somehow.

Comment: Are the client and server computers enrolled in an Active Directory Domain or are they using ad-hoc filesharing?

Comment: I think it is ad-hoc filesharing. But, I am going to try to see how to enable Active Directory Domain.

Comment: this how to find shared files on windows .
http://compnetworking.about.com/cs/winxpnetworking/ht/findwinshares.htm

Answer (score 1):

try mapping network drive on your client ?

Comment: The mapped drive is not accessible from Firefox open file dialog. Also, I cannot practically map drive on all 700+ clients. To make it worse, the client get added and removed frequently.

Comment: have you try something like this before . http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N3apMuBTeBM

Comment: Thanks! I just tried this. I could fallow almost all the steps in the video on my Win 2008 R2.Only problem I am getting: when I right click on one of domain I don't see a "new" option. So, I don't know how to publish my shared folder to a domain.